# virtual directory path name in angular 2

Tags: angular

How can I get virtual directory path name in angular 2?
 we have **HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath** Property in c#.net but how to use in angular 2.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance